# Pythonic way to access keys of sub dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I frequently work with nested dicts (e.g. created from `json.loads()`) where sometimes the deeper level dicts will vary. **I would like to find a more elegant, Pythonic way to access the sub-dicts without a lot of nested `if` statements.**

```
data = some_func()
if 'network_data' in data:
    print "\n## IP Info"
    if 'hostname' in data['network_data']:
        print "- Hostname: %s" % data['network_data']['hostname']
    if 'org' in data['network_data']:
        print "- Org: %s" % data['network_data']['org']
    if 'city' in data['network_data'] and 'country' in data['network_data'] and 'region' in data['network_data']:
        print "- Location: %s, %s, %s" % (data['network_data']['city'],
                                          data['network_data']['country'],
                                          data['network_data']['region'])
```

(repeat various versions of that `if` statement for other possible sub-dicts, possibly going even deeper).

I know about the `.get()` function for dicts but then I run into problems where some of the mid-level dicts don't exist:

```
ddos = []
for each in vcdb:
    variety = each.get('action').get('hacking').get('variety')
    if 'DoS' in variety:
        ddos.append(each)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-40616b7d85d0> in <module>()
      1 ddos = []
      2 for each in vcdb:
----> 3     variety = each.get('action').get('hacking').get('variety')
      4     if 'DoS' in variety:
      5         ddos.append(each)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) accepts a `default` parameter and you can take advantage of that, like this

```
variety = each.get('action', {}).get('hacking', {}).get('variety', {})
```

So, even if the subsequent keys are not found in the sub dict, it will return an empty dict, instead of failing.